# How can I change the width of the uiview depending on the length of label (string) in tableview cell?

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to create a chat app like Messenger and Line.
In chat app, the length of colored background views behind messages changes depending on that of messages. 
How can I achieve this?
This is xib file to display in tableview cell.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD0d3.jpg

Comment: I followed this tutorial for creating chat bubbles, it worked for me: https://robkerr.com/tutorial-creating-an-ios-chat-bubble-with-tails-in-swift-the-easy-way-9f4db2c26aa

Answer (score 0):

`intrinsicContentSize` property of `UILabel` will have its preferred size based on its content.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIView` method `sizeToFit()`. For `UILabel`, this sizes the label to fit it's text.